# Spring.NET + NHibernate + request scoped objects not playing well together

Tags: nhibernate, dependency-injection, spring.net, open-session-in-view

I'm using Spring.NET 1.3.2, NHibernate 3.1 and the OSIV pattern in a ASP.NET application.

I have a custom `EventListener` that needs to be **request** scoped because it uses 
HttpContext.Current.Items as a constructor dependency.

Since `ISession` is also **request** scoped, I should be able to use Spring.NET to manage these dependencies for me.

The problem is that  `EventListener`, like `IInterceptor`, is a property of `ISessionFactory` which is **not** request scoped (it's a singleton). The mismatch between the web object scopes is problematic.

I tried the following XML snippet, but the conditional expression always yields null. I think this is due to Spring creating `EventListener` object at an application level scope, and before `HttpContext.Current.Items` has had a chance to be populated.

```
  <object id="EventListener" scope="request" type="MyEventListener,DAL">

        <constructor-arg index="0" expression="T(System.Web.HttpContext).Current.Items.Contains('Principal')?T(System.Web.HttpContext).Current.Items['Principal']:null"/>

  </object>
```

So my requirement is:

1. Configure custom `EventListener` object in Spring so that it is created **on a per-request basis**
2. `EventListener` instantiation must occur late enough in the request lifecycle so that HttpContext.Current.Items['Princpial'] has been populated by a custom IHttpModule
3. The `EventListener` instance is injected into the the current OSIV `ISession`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to do this the wrong way around. According to the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events) `EventListener`s should basically be considered singletons for your application.

Even when you register your custom `EventListener` with the `SessionFactory`, say at the start of the request, you still have no guarantee whatsoever that this listener will *only* receive events raised in the current `HttpContext`.

Instead you should register your eventhandlers globally, when configuring the session factory. If you need context information, such as a principal, you can inject a dependency with a (http)context-aware implementation or implement it as an [ambient context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx).

From the custom listener, you can get access to the session that raised the event. Take for instance this `ILoadEventListener` implementation:

```
public class CustomLoadEventListener : ILoadEventListener
{
    private IPrincipalProvider _principalProvider;

    public CustomLoadEventListener(IPrincipalProvider provider)
    {
        _principalProvider = provider;
    }

    public void OnLoad(LoadEvent @event, LoadType loadType)
    {
        var sessionThatRaisedTheEvent = @event.Session;
        var principalForTheCurrentContext = _principalProvider.GetCurrentPrincipal();
    }
}

public interface IPrincipalProvider
{
    IPrincipal GetCurrentPrincipal();
}

public class HttpContextPrincipalProvider : IPrincipalProvider
{
    public IPrincipal GetCurrentPrincipal()
    {
        return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
    }
}
```

This might not be the answer you hoped to get, but IMO what your are asking for would be fighting the infrastructure, which I generally try to avoid.

If you post some more details on what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to propose a better solution. What should your `EventListener` do?